# JList highlight row issue

Tags: java, forms, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I'm trying to highlight all rows in a JList which have been "matched" with data elsewhere, and disable that row. 
When I debug, I can see the correct data is set within cbNameIsMatched. However, what happens instead is that after I create the first match, each row I select in the JList is highlighted instead of the one with the "matched" index. The `setEnabled` is also setting for all items from the end of the list up to where I click in the list.

```
class MyListCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer
        {
            public MyCopybookListCellRenderer()
            {
                setOpaque(false);
            }

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList paramList, Object value,
                    int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) 
            {
                setText(value.toString());

                if(isSelected)
                {
                    setOpaque(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    setOpaque(false);
                }

                if(cbNameIsMatched[index]==2)
                {
                    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    setEnabled(false);                      
                }

                myList.repaint();

                return this;
            }
```

Comment: Use `setOpaque(isSelected)` instead of the `if - else`.

Comment: No problem. What is your selection model? Can you select only a single cell or many cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do better extending `DefaultListCellRenderer` over `JLabel` as the former already takes care of everything and all you have to do is change the specific things you need. It gives you a "safety net" for the cases you didn't touch.

```
public class GetterText extends JFrame {

    GetterText() {

        JList<String> list = new JList<>(new String[]{"AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD"});
        list.setCellRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer());

        getContentPane().add(list);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            label.setOpaque(isSelected); // Highlight only when selected
            label.setOpaque(true); // Highlight always
            if(index == 2) { // I faked a match for the second index, put you matching condition here.
                label.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                label.setEnabled(false);     
            }
            return label;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GetterText();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** elaboration on the use of `super`

`super` gives a reference to the superclass which you can use to call its methods. When overriding a method of the superclass, calling that superclass's method means "do what you did before", or, "retain the implementation". This is good because you start from a point where everything works as the default and what you have left to do is tweak specific behaviors without the need to take care for all the others.

In this case, if you return `label` after

```
JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
```

you would get the default behavior because it is the one being used by the extending `DefaultListCellRenderer`. The arguments are the same in order to get the same result as the superclass would give. Then I go on to change this default `JLabel`. What you do is create a new `JLabel` with no default behavior. Note that I "cheat" here by knowing that the `Component` returned by `DefaultListCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent` is a `JLabel`.

Comment: I want the highlight when the cell matched the corresponding index as you have it in your code. Where I'm at now, I can't get setOpaque to work at all. Clicking the cell does not highlight it to the default (greyish color), but the hightlighting/disabling does work currently. I used another example found which is why I extend Jlabel, but I honestly don't know why it was used in the first place.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you use this line: `JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);` ? Do the method variables not already contain this data?

Comment: I tried your solution and it works great, but the cell only highlights yellow if it's the active (selected) cell, and I'm trying to highlight all of matches, which I believe is related to the opaque setting

Comment: @JWiley Those are already explained in my answer. (1) I use the `super` method to get the default implementation and then change it. (2) See the comment in my code.

Comment: @JWiley I added explanations in my post.

Answer (score 1):

`ListCellRenderer` acts like a stamp. The same instance with the same data is reused. You have to set the correct color every time.

```
if(cbNameIsMatched[index]==2)
{
    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    setEnabled(false);                      
}
else
{
    setBackground(your default color);
    setEnabled(true);                      
}
```

Comment: I've gotten to that step, but now I'm unable to show an item in that same list is selected when I want to make a match. The setOpaque() also seems to determine whether or not anything shows up at all, so getting the order right seems important as well...

Comment: In other words, the list is now highlighting correct items after matching, but I can't see the selection I make i.e. setOpaque isn't doing anything